# java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo for register and login

Tags: java, android

> java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.earljames.register_login/com.example.earljames.register_login.Home}: java.lang.NullPointerException

Here's my code for my home page.

```
public class  Home extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {

    Button bLogout;
    EditText etUsername, etName, etAge;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_register);

        etUsername = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etUsername);
        etName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etName);
        etAge = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etAge);
        bLogout = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bLogout);

        bLogout.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        switch (view.getId()){
            case R.id.bLogout:
                startActivity(new Intent(this,Login.class));
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

**Androidmanifest.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity android:name=".Home">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".Login" />
    <activity
        android:name=".Register"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_register"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar"></activity>
</application>
```

**Activity_Register.xml**

```
<TextView
    android:text="Name"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

<EditText
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/etName"
    android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"/>

<TextView
    android:text="Age"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

<EditText
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/etAge"
    android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"/>

<TextView
    android:text="Username"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

<EditText
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/etUsername"
    android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"/>

<TextView
    android:text="Password"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

<EditText
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/etPassword"
    android:inputType="textPassword"
    android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"/>

<Button
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:text="Register"
    android:id="@+id/bRegister"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

Comment: Can you post entire crash log

Comment: Did you add the Login activity in the AndroidManifest.xml?

Comment: where can i find AndroidManfest.xml?

Comment: Added **AndroidManifest.xml** file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess that is something related to the `activity_register` xml. Please check that the Button id `bLogout` exists and it is spelled correctly.

Comment: there's no Logout Button in the activity_register.xml, only "Register" Button

Comment: yes, that's why your app crashes... You are referring to a button whose id is bLogout but it does not exist in the xml

Comment: uploaded my androidmanifest.xml file i think the problem is there

Comment: Could you please post the activity_register.xml file?

Comment: posted the register.xml file

Comment: ok modify `bLogout = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bLogout);` into `bLogout = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bRegister);`

Comment: WOW YOU ARE AMAZING! HAHA THANK YOU SO MUCH !

Comment: i got a problem. when i click register it wont go to the login page. like it doesnt do any action at all

Comment: yes you're right. Modify also `case R.id.bLogout:` into `case R.id.bRegister:`

Answer (score 2):

Probably what im able to see is problem with ur this variable

Try with HOME.this

And still it wont work write this lines

Intent i = new Intent(Home.this,Ur new activity.class)
i.setFlag(Intent.FLAG_NEWACTIVITY)
StartActivity(i)

Comment: sorry but im a newbie and i dont seem to understand how                  Intent i = new Intent(Home.this,Ur new activity.class) i.setFlag(Intent.FLAG_NEWACTIVITY) StartActivity(i     Works

Answer (score 1):

Presently, you the `this` in the line `startActivity(new Intent(this,Login.class));` is passing a reference to the `View` whereas you actually need a reference to the Activity that you are presently in.

Change to:

```
startActivity(new Intent(Home.this, Login.class));
```

Comment: tried this but when i clicked the app it says "Unfortunately , Register_Login has stopped